# C# trigger, Surround SCM & werfault.exe

Tags: c#, debugging

We are in the process of setting up surround scm as our source control program. We created a trigger which will run when changing the state of a file/repository. When we run it on many files the server gets several werfault.exe processes in the process list. I realize its windows error reporting, however, there is no popup. I'm trying to determine the cause of the error... is there a specific log I can check, or a debugging technique I can use? I don't believe it will be possible to debug directly on the server it runs on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was happening was that we set a trigger on certain events and the trigger calls the handling exe simultaneously, which was swamping the server. We're now using an alternate solution with a windows service so we can control the max amount of simultaneous trigger executions.

Answer (score 0):

WER faults end up in the Event Log, so that might give you a tiny clue, though it's usually not enough info to tell what went wrong. Maybe you want to add more logging to your trigger application, or have it run [userdump.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241215) when it's about to crash (see AppDomain.UnhandledException event) to a specific folder - that way you can open up the crash dumps later to figure out what went pear-shaped.